Should I get into BJJ with my current body metrics?
So I'm planning to get into Jiu Jitsu but I'm 32years old ,125Kgs (275lbs) with a height of 6 feet. I'm fat yes but have had a history of playing basketball but that too was about 12-14 years ago.
I'm afraid of any injuries at my current body weight because I cannot afford an injury at this stage (health wise).
Please guide me.
P.S. I live in India.


I cannot afford an injury at this stage

This is simple. Do not start a high-intensity combat sport if injuries are a major concern. This is 10x true if you are out of shape.
Instead, plan out a gradual plan to get fit. Allow yourself at least a year. Ideally, include both strength and conditioning -- don't focus too much on one thing.

I understand the worry you have about injury given your poor physical condition. The important thing is you know you have limits, and so you won't feel bad when you can't do what the other guys in class are doing. You're not there yet. And if you choose a more experienced (grey haired) black belt instructor in BJJ, you will likely have a better time. That's because with age, everyone experiences their body's limitations and has to adjust their own training accordingly. An older, more experienced BJJ instructor might be able to understand your condition better.
BJJ schools have a reputation of training hard and developing athletic bodies. It's not going to be easy. Your physical condition will make you stand out from the rest at first. You'll become exhausted very quickly. At least for the first year or so. Then, if you've been pushing yourself enough, your body will improve. And eventually, if you stick with it, your physical condition might actually normalize. You might be a different man after a long time.
Another thing you'll find is BJJ people encourage each other at a good school. Nobody will laugh at you. Nobody will point. If anything, they'll be there encouraging you and cheering you on, especially when you start improving. They'll be your biggest fans.
I've been in your position before, sort of. I have a knee condition that makes hard training very difficult. If I'm going into some new form of exercise like BJJ as a couch potato, completely out of shape, then that's going to be a very quick and horrible experience for me. My knees will simply lock up, and it will require weeks of recovery. I won't even be coming back.
So I don't go into new exercise programs as a couch potato. I do a little bit of preparation first. For me, that makes sense. I need to build up the muscles around my knees in order for them to be able to handle the loads. Then that will protect my knees enough so that I can do the new exercise program. Without that, I know that if I try it, I will hurt myself.
Ideally, you should never let your physical condition become poor, like a couch potato. But life happens. We get older. We get a career and kids. It's easy to neglect your body. And so if you are in poor shape, and you know there's something about your body that requires attention first (like my knees), then you have to work on that first before doing a serious new exercise program.
If you don't have any limiting physical problems other than your weight and weak muscle strength, then I would say you're ready to begin BJJ training. But, do have a conversation first with the instructor, and make sure he knows you can't push yourself as hard as the others just yet. You don't want to have a stroke or a heart attack or something at your age. If the instructor is good, he'll understand what you're saying. But you still can't relax in your BJJ training. You have to put in good effort, as much as you can without hurting yourself. It's going to exhaust you. And in time, that's how you're going to change everything about your body.
One other thing. Now is a good time to get in a complete check-up with your doctor. Ask if there's any medical reason why you shouldn't begin BJJ. I always think that's a good idea for anyone, but especially for people who are overweight or who haven't exercised in a long time.
Hope that helps.

Thanks a lot. Yes I'll have a talk with my bjj instructor and if I feel he's not paying much attention to it then I'll switch gyms.
